# How can I configure TCP client to go through proxy via localhost?

Tags: networking, tcp, proxy, wireshark, http-proxy

Currently I am using SwiftNIO and have a echo server and client. I was using SquidMan to create a local proxy, then I configured the proxy on my machine via system preferences. When I look at my Wireshark captures, I only see packets go directly from my client to my server and vice-versa. How can I configure it so that my client must go through the proxy first?

Note: I've also tried running my server on a VM and running a proxy on a separate Windows Laptop on my Network.

When I go to `System Preferences -> Advance -> Network -> Proxies` on my Mac I configured HTTPS/HTTP to point to the proxy I have running on my Windows Laptop. Is there something more I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

on the machine running SwiftNIO echo server/client service, repoint your TCP/IP default gateway to the address of your Proxy server....proxy server will then NAT translate for your SwiftNIO and return correct packets on your behalf

I may not be understanding your issue, but this seems easy

Comment: When I go to `System Preferences -> Advance -> Network -> Proxies` on my Mac I configured HTTPS/HTTP to point to the proxy I have running on my Windows Laptop. Is there something more I have to do?